# framelayout how to get content?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

Since I had to do a custom menu for my application, I've made a fragment which act like an actionbar at the bottom of my app!

But I have some conflicts with the stack (when pressing the back button).

How should I program the following method?

```
public void changerContenu(int frameLayout, Fragment frag, boolean ajouterAuStack)
{
    if(R.id.frameContent != frag.getId()) 
// * if the current displaying
// fragment in the layout is the same as the one that I received in param#2 (frag),   
// then don't do anything.
    {
        ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(frameLayout, frag);
        if(ajouterAuStack)
            ft.addToBackStack(null);

        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

I know my "if" doesn't make any sense right now, trying to figure out how to come to the desired result :( Right now, when I visit the fragment once (and it's pushed into the stack) I cannot revisit it using my button in my "home made actionbar" until I hit the back button a few times to clean the stack.

I only want to not duplicate items in my stack if I click few times the same button on my menu...

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I got it working that way:

```
public void changerContenu(int frameLayout, Fragment frag, boolean ajouterAuStack, String tag)
{
    ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(frameLayout, frag);
    if(ajouterAuStack && (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0 
            || fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getName() != tag))
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);

    ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to understand the question better.

You have a fragment that acts like an action bar. If the fragment is already displaying, you don't want to do anything; otherwise, you want to display it. In what circumstances do you want to go Back, and what should happen?

As a note, a single actionbar at the bottom doesn't fit in with the typical Android design. Users may not understand how to use your app. I'm interested in knowing why the regular ActionBar doesn't work for you.

Comment: I would had used an actionbar, but the company I'm working with wanted a particular design where I cannot use an actionbar to represent it. So I designed it in a fragment which act like a "tab menu".
I got 2 frameLayers, one with my menu (let's say A) and another one on top of it for displaying my content (B).

If I hit 10 times one of my buttons in my menu fragment in frameLayer A, it'll execute 10 times the code I showed up in my first post. I don't want that, since it will add the fragment 10x in the backstack and I'll have to hit "Back" 10 times to get out of this fragment.

Hope it help!